# Searching for part of string item in a list?

Tags: string, list, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a list where the items in the list have a complicated construction ( A concatenation of strings from different variables created elsewhere in the program). 
I would like to search for part of the string in the list using an "if i in list" type function. Can I do this? If so what is the syntax?

Additional info: the string I'd like to search for in the list item is around 500 characters long and held in a variable. In the list items there are \t and \n plus other string characters as eventually these list items are output into a text file list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of help I realised I needed to loop through the list items and use the "in" command there: ie..

[f for f in list if seq in f]